# NSMutableDictionary caching and/or size limiting

Tags: ios, caching, limit, game-center

I'm using a NSMutableDictionary to cache high scores that I pull from Game Center (storing scores by GC rank as key). The pulling happens as soon as the user views that line in a tableview. If there are a million rows and the user views them all, that would mean that the cache fills up to a million rows...
Ok in practice I guess I'll be happy if a million people played my game but still to be on the safe side I'd like to limit the amount of rows that go into the NSMutableDictionary.

Anyone got a simple approach here? Maybe another structure than a dictionary would be useful. My idea was to remove the entries from the dictionary that were the most old, and out of current tableview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken a look at `NSCache`? *･゜ﾟ･*:.｡..｡.:*･'(*ﾟ▽ﾟ*)'･*:.｡. .｡.:*･゜ﾟ･*